# Problema con useState() de React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datagrid, material-ui, usestate

La idea es que al presionar una celda de mi **DataGrid** se dispare un **Dialog**. Si bien se dispara y es mostrado, no se puede quitar.

**DataGrid.tsx**:

```
export default function Data(props: any) {
  const { columns, rows } = props;

  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleDialogOpen = () => setDialogOpen(true);

  const handleValue = (e: any): void => {
    if (e) {
      console.log(e.row);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" className="Container">
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: '84%', cursor: 'pointer' }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          onCellClick={(e: any) => {
            handleValue(e);
            handleDialogOpen();
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <Dialog open={dialogOpen} onClose={handleDialogOpen} />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

**Dialog.tsx**:

```
export default function AlertDialogSlide(props: any) {
  const { open, onClose } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={onClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle>Use Google location service?</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
            Error
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={onClose}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Lo único que no estoy pudiendo hacer es que el Button de Dialog cierre el pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que necesitas usar useEffect(). Usa el cambio de la variable active para afectar la conducta que esperas.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

useEffect( () => {

if (dialogOpen) {
…
}

}, [dialogOpen]);

Comment: Hice una actualización del código de Dialog.tsx; con active así como propones no me ha funcionado. En cambio, intenté con status y tanto para abrir como cerrar, funciona. Ahora el único inconveniente es que si vuelvo a presionar otra celda, ya no funciona el Dialog.

Comment: Ya veo. Cómo estás tratando de comunicar entre dos componentes, se me hace que vas a necesitar alguna herramienta que gestione state. Como redux. O, puedes hacer mostrar/esconde <Dialog /> con style según el valor de dialogOpen